# facebook fql query similar to friends checkins

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

Looking for the fql equivalente to the search below.  Looking to get all checkins by friends and the name of the place.

https://graph.facebook.com/search?type=checkin&access_token=...

### EDIT

temp_time = 2 weeks ago

If below, gets me the the page ID(place) and Author ID (user) of checkins

```
SELECT author_uid, page_id FROM checkin WHERE timestamp > #{temp_time} AND author_uid IN(SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me())
```

What would be the sql or fql statement to include the user name and place details with the response.  Ideally, would be user with the place detail in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the name of the location is the same as it's respective page:

```
SELECT checkin_id, author_uid, page_id FROM checkin 
WHERE author_uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) 
AND page_id IN (SELECT page_id FROM page WHERE name = 'PAGE NAME')
```

---

FQL only permits one table within the FROM clause, as such, I don't think it is possible to get all the data you want from a single FQL statement because you would require data from both [user](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user/) and [page](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/page/) tables.

Comment: Hi jBit, I edited the question to explain more.  Looking to get the Friend name and Place details of a checkin that belongs to my friends

Comment: And now I understand.  Off to fql.multiquery.   Thanks!