# How to search for friends around me using Facebook API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Using GraphAPI, I see you can request location of a specific friend, or search for friends by criteria.

However, I couldn't find a way to search for friends in my area. I want to perform a search and get a results of friends who are in a radius of X meters from me.

I know I can fetch each friend manually and check its location, but it seems a bit inefficient so I'm looking for a batch search,

EDIT: I've found a similar question (and answer) using FQL: [facebook fql query similar to friends checkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6947647/facebook-fql-query-similar-to-friends-checkins)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you partly answered yourself there...

When you query about a user friend, you get his location as well since it's part of the User object (assuming you have the right permissions of course): http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/

The problem, as you wrote, is that you'll need to send a request to facebook per friend, which is not the right way to go about this.
Thankfully, facebook already thought of that and they came up with the "Batch Requests": http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/ which let you do exactly that.

**EDIT**

Now that I think of it, it's simpler than I wrote before, you don't even need the batch requests since you can get all of the user friends in one request to: me/friends.
Assuming you have the user granted you the needed permissions each user object in the friends list will have the location object as well.

For each friend calculate if his location is in the desired radius.

Comment: Thanks, but I was looking for a single query which can simply return me an array of friends around me without batching 500 requests.

Comment: In addition, batch requests are limited to 50 requests.

Comment: I think that you are missing the point of the graph api. The api just gives you the graphs nodes and their connections to other nodes, but it's up to the different applications to use graph algorithms and come up with different things to do with them. I can ask for all of my friend who have radius of X from me based on the number of likes we have in common. you can't expect facebook to implement all of the available applications of their graph

Comment: As for the batch request being limited to only 50: users on facebook has an average of 150 friends (I can't find an up to date official number, this is the closest: http://blog.facebook.com/blog.php?post=72975227130) so on average you'll need to make only 3 batch requests, way better than 150 don't you think?

Comment: "I can ask for all of my friend who have radius of X from me based on the number of likes we have in common". Maybe I did miss on how to use it, hence why I'm asking here :). How can I perform the query you've mentioned?

Comment: :) I was trying to give you an example of another "complicated" operation someone might need in their application. The fact are that there are probably infinite number of operations that can be performed on the fb graph, and it's up to you as the developer of the app to implement such an operation. I'll edit my answer with a pseudo code of how I think you should approach this.

Answer (score 1):

Also, you can retrieve friends location and hometown using this Graph API endpoint: **/me/friends?fields=location,hometown,name**

But you will need the friends_location and friends_hometown permissions.

Read more: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/extended-profile-properties/

Comment: Thanks, but using this I can only get their exact location (and compare to mine). I was looking for a way to get their latitude/longitude.